# Visual Basic (mistakes in code)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Visual Studio.I tried to write a simple program in Visual Basic that takes a 13-digit number from a text box and writes its digits to an array.Then it writes the second member of the array (second digit of the number) to another text box, but it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim array(12) As Integer
        Dim index As Integer = 11
        Dim code As Long = TextBox1.Text
        Do While index >= 0
            array(index) = code Mod 10
            code /= 10
            index -= 1
        Loop
        TextBox2.Text = array(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Forgotten VB, but isn't it: `code = code / 10` and `index = index - 1`. Also I would not use "array" as name.

Comment: Option Strict Off, this is the biggest error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim array(12) As Integer
    Dim index As Integer = 11
    Dim code As Char() = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray()

    For i As Integer = 0 To code.Count - 1
        array(i) = Integer.Parse(code(i))
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = array(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I used to make programs with C++ and didn't know that in Visual Basic I can easily convert digits in char to integer.